# Check if word in dictionary and get value from another column

Tags: r

I have these two datasets:

```
stemmed <- data.frame(
  stem = c('super puper', 'only for you')
)


super <- data.frame(
  word = c('super', 'puper', 'you'),
  weight = c(0.5, 0.1, 0.3)
)
```

I check if a word is in the positive-and-negative dictionary and calculate how many times. I have a loop like this:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(stemmed)){
  words = strsplit(as.character(stemmed$stem)," ")
  stemmed$super[i] <- sum(words[[i]] %in% super$word)/length(words[[i]])
}
```

(By the way if you know how to improve this code, please tell me.)

Now I want to calculate not only the number of words but the weight (sum of weights of words, contained in `super$weight`).

So I tried to do something like this in the loop:

```
if (words[[i]] %in% super$word) {
 stemmed$super[i] = sum(with super[super$word==words[[i]],], 
                        sum(super$weight))}
```

I want to get a data frame like this:

```
stem             super
super puper      0.6
only for you     0.3
```

I don`t know how to solve this issue...

Comment: `colSums(t(sapply(super$word, grepl, stemmed$stem))*super$weight)`

Comment: following your mind flow, the `match` may be the function you need

Answer (score 0):

There are loads of way of doing this.
By following your approach, I would wrap it into a sapply

```
> final <- stemmed
> final$super <- sapply(stemmed$stem, function(x) {
  sum(super$weight[super$word %in% unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), " "))])
})
> final
           stem super
1  super puper   0.6
2 only for you   0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> data.frame(stem=stemmed$stem,
       super=sapply(lapply(strsplit(as.character(stemmed$stem), " ") ,
                           function(txt) super$word %in% txt),
                    function(idx) sum(super$weight[idx])))
          stem super
1  super puper   0.6
2 only for you   0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution for your, but I used data.tables instead of data.frames. The advantage of this solution is that no apply/looping is used.

```
library("data.table")
library("reshape2")
stemmed <- data.frame(
    stem = c('super puper', 'only for you')
)

super <- data.table(
    word = c('super', 'puper', 'you'),
    weight = c(0.5, 0.1, 0.3)
)


# Step 1: Split the words
split_words <- strsplit(as.character(stemmed$stem), " ")
names(split_words) <- stemmed$stem
# Step 2: melt it to a data.table
result <- data.table(melt(split_words))
setnames(result, names(result), c("word", "stem"))
# Step 3: Find the weight by merging it with super
setkey(super, word)
setkey(result, word)
word_weights <- super[result]
# Step 4: Filter the NA weights
word_weights <- word_weights[!is.na(weight)]
# Step 5: Now aggregate by stem to find the weight per stem
final_result <- word_weights[, list(super = sum(weight)), by = stem]
> final_result
           stem super
1:  super puper   0.6
2: only for you   0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `match`.

```
stemmed <- data.frame(
  stem = c('super puper', 'only for you')
)

super <- data.frame(
  word = c('super', 'puper', 'you'),
  weight = c(0.5, 0.1, 0.3)
)

# this line may be out of loop
words <- strsplit(as.character(stemmed$stem)," ")

for (i in 1:nrow(stemmed)){
  stemmed$super[i] <- sum(words[[i]] %in% super$word)/length(words[[i]])
  # get weights for super words
  w.index <- na.exclude(match(words[[i]],super$word))
  if (length(w.index) > 0) stemmed$super[i] <- sum(super$weight[w.index])

}

#~ > stemmed
#~           stem super
#~ 1  super puper   0.6
#~ 2 only for you   0.3
```